# GHC 8 and still the error "Multiple declarations of myDataField123"

Tags: haskell

I have 2 data's with the fields named the same:

```
data Data1 = Data1 { var1 :: String }
data Data2 = Data2 { var1 :: String }
```

Also in my 'stack.yaml' I have this:

```
resolver: lts-7.11
```

which makes it to use GHC 8.01 which must  deal with this issue. However, it still doesn't and the error is:

```
 Multiple declarations of ‘var1'’
```

Comment: You probably need to enable some kind of extension like [DuplicateRecordFields](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Records/OverloadedRecordFields/DuplicateRecordFields)

Comment: Add `{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}` to the top of your file.

Comment: @n.m., but hasn't that been embedded into the language or compiler  since ghc 8.0 with no extensions needed?

Comment: No, I don't think it was ever in the plans.

Comment: Furtunately not! I consider `DuplicateRecordFields` a step in the wrong direction, clobbering the language's simplicity to solve a problem that [can better be adressed on the library level](https://nikita-volkov.github.io/record/).

Comment: @leftaroundabout I agree, but I can't help wishing GHC would generate Van Laarhoven lenses from records instead of projection functions.